# Turn off and disable the "Coherence" feature of Parallels Desktop for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, settings, parallels-desktop

On Parallels 15.0.0, I have accidentally triggered the "Coherence" feature within a VM running macOS Catalina as a guest on my macOS Mojave host. Now the apps are opening in within native windows on host machine, rather than being contained within a single "desktop" window. This is unworkable for me, making Parallels worse than worthless.

➥ How do I turn off the now-active "Coherence" feature within a VM?

➥ How do I entirely disable the "Coherence" entirely, so I never accidentally invoke it again?

I tried turning on the `Configuration` > `Security` > `Isolate virtual machine from Mac`. But this did not stop the Coherence feature.

Answer (score 5):

## Choose `Exit` > `Coherence`

To get out of the now-active "Coherence" mode, bring the "desktop" window to the front.

While the VM’s windows have "flown the coop" and no longer display within the desktop window, that desktop window does continue to exist. If you cannot find the window, on the host macOS, press Command+Tab to see the switcher bar with various app icons. Switch to the icon of a grey Apple logo with a pair of red vertical bars layered on.

With the desktop window in front, on the host macOS window bar for the VM, choose `View` > `Exit Coherence`. All your app windows snap back to the desktop window.

[image]

That takes care of half your Question. Perhaps someone else can post on how to kill the Coherence feature entirely.

Comment: I haven't jumped to v15 yet, I tend to wait a couple of revisions before upgrading - it looks like they've removed the Coherence hot key. It used to be Cmd/Ctrl/C & would show as such in that menu or in the 'Windows' menu in your Mac's menu bar, the red || icon. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMTfB.png also, their KB - https://kb.parallels.com/4670